# grep between two list

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file (`list.txt`) containing a list of objects and another file `informations.txt` that contain a longer list of objects in the first column (containing also the objects of the file 1) and in the others columns some variables. I need to extract from the file `informations.txt` only the line that regarding the objects present in file `list.txt`.
Example:

```
list.txt:
1ert3_001_______
4rt41_004_______

informations.txt: All the column are separated by "tab"
1ert3_001_______ GVT YTR 456
76ftr_008_______ TRF cFR 3k9
r45e9_001_______ YTG %&Y TF2
4rt41_004_______ %&/ ldu DR4

result.txt:
1ert3_001_______ GVT YTR 456
4rt41_004_______ %&/ ldu DR4
```

I tried to use the comand grep but I didn't obtain the desidered results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the GNU grep, combine -f --file with -F --fixed-strings to search fixed (non regex) patterns from file:

```
grep --fixed-strings --file list.txt informations.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read p; do
  grep -i "$p" informations.txt
done <list.txt
```

Try this.